# Distribution of the argmax of Brownian motion.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B:\Omega\times[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a standard Brownian motion starting at zero defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb P)$.
For any $a\in[0,1]$, I am interested in $$F(a):=\mathbb P\{\omega\in\Omega:\mathrm{argmax}_{t\in[0,1]}B_t(\omega)\leq a\}$$
This is the cdf of a random variable in $[0,1]$. Notice that this is well defined because the argmax is unique almost surely. (See Th2.11 of Mörters-Peres)

Comment: I guess it's somehow related with Chernoff's distribution.

Comment: I found the answer. $F(a)=2 \mathrm{arcsin}(\sqrt{x})/\pi$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_laws_(Wiener_process) So that the argmax is distributed as a Beta(1/2,1/2) random variable.